# Is it possible to replace or alias core modules in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, module

I'm currently working on a project where one of the core Node.js modules (dns) does not behave the way I need it to. I've found a module that seems like it would work as a replacement: https://github.com/tjfontaine/node-dns. However, the code using the DNS module is several layers down from the application code I've written. I'm using the Request module (https://github.com/mikeal/request) which makes HTTP requests and uses several core modules to do so. The Request module does not seem to be using the DNS module directly, but I'm assuming  one of those core modules is calling the DNS module.

Is there a way I can tell Node to use https://github.com/tjfontaine/node-dns whenever require('dns') is called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and you should not,

require.cache is a dangerous thing, extremely. It can cause memory leaks if you do not know what you are doing and cache mismatch which is potentially worse. Most requests to change core modules can also result in unintentional side effects (such as discoverability failures with DNS).

You can create a user-space require with something like : https://github.com/bmeck/node-module-system ; however, this faces the same dangers but is not directly tied to core.

My suggestion would be to wrap your require('dns').resolve with require('async').memoize, but be aware that DNS discoverability may fall over.

Answer (score 3):

For better or worse, I've implemented module white lists before doing something as demonstrated below. In your case, it ought to be possible to explicitly check for `dns` module name and delegate everything else to original `require()`. However, this implementation assumes that you have full control of when and how your own code is being executed.

```
var _require = constructMyOwnRequire(/*intercept 'dns' and require something else*/);

var sandbox = Object.freeze({
    /* directly import all other globals like setTimeout, setInterval, etc.. */
    require : Object.freeze(_require)
});

try {
    vm.runInContext(YOUR_SCRIPT, Object.freeze(vm.createContext(sandbox)));
} catch (exception) {
    /* stuff */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

`require` is a core var which is local to each module, so you can't stub it, because Node will give the untouched `require` var to the loaded module.

You could run those things using the [`vm`](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) module. However, you would have to write too much code to do a "simple workaround" (give all needed variables to the request module, stub the needed ones to work properly, etc, etc...).